# unable to get property 'getRegularPolygon' of undefined or null

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, bing-maps

I use invokescript in C# to call on SetCoords and it seems like everything's working fine until it runs into the "getRegularPolygon" line. I can't find any documentation for the method but I got the second half of the SetCoords function from this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/spatial-math-module-examples/geolocation-accuracy-circle-example
Other places I've looked for answers say something about "getelementbyid" but that doesn't seem to apply here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key={mykey}' async defer></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' async defer>
        var map, infobox, pushpin, radius;
        var centerlattitude = 0.0;
        var centerlongitude = 0.0;
        
        function GetMap() {
            var center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(centerlattitude, centerlongitude);
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', { center: center, zoom: 20 });
            pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(centerlattitude, centerlongitude + 0.0005), { draggable: true });
            map.entities.push(pushpin);
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'changed', getNewCenter);
        }
        function SetCoords(lat, long, rad) {
            centerlattitude = lat;
            centerlongitude = long;
            radius = rad;
            GetMap();
            var path = Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.getRegularPolygon(center, radius*1000, 8, Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.Meters);
            var poly = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(path);
            map.entities.push(poly);
        }
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the spatial math library. Bing Maps is modularized to help reduce the overall size of applications so that developers only load in the parts they need to ensure fast initial loading of the app. Note that loading of modules is asynchronous, so you have to run your code that accesses the module, after it has finished loading. Here is an example:

```
//Load the spatial math module
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath", function () {
    var path = Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.getRegularPolygon(center, radius*1000, 8, Microsoft.Maps.SpatialMath.Meters);
    var poly = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(path);
    map.entities.push(poly);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but after what has finished loading? I ran the code and it doesn't give an error anymore but the polygon just doesn't show up.

Comment: Nevermind, it works. I moved the loadmodule part into the GetMap function and it works now. Thanks.